# Как ввести команду в консоль через python

Tags: python-3.x

Допустим надо ввести в самом коде команду в консоль на WINDOWS и сохранить ответ в отдельную переменную,если это возможно

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно:

```
network = os.popen('ifconfig').read()
```

или так (от пользователя [BackTrack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/330518/backtrack)):

```
perem = os.system('echo it\'s working!')
```